# WSO2 H2 Database

Tags: h2, wso2

In the WSO2 documentation you  state that the embedded H2 database is suitable for development. However, for most enterprise testing and production environments we recommend an industry-standard RDBMS such as Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, MS SQL, etc. (https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon420/Working+with+Databases)

Can you kindly give us some use cases where H2 Databases are suitable for production environments?

How can we better assess if the H2 Database is suitable or not for our production environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not recommend H2 Database to be used in production. However H2 is recommended to be used as the "Local" Registry. See "Registry and governance" in [Production Deployment Guidelines](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Production+Deployment+Guidelines).

See also [Sharing Databases](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Sharing+Databases)

I answered a similar question before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23090822/1955702

Answer (score -1):

In my case, it was perfectly suitable for testing project on build time. In-memory database have been used to store some lookup table values. Very simple usage as follows:

pom.xml

```
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.193</version>
        <scope>testing</scope>
    </dependency>
...
</dependencies>
...
```

Test class

```
...
@BeforeClass
public static void setupOnce() throws SQLException {
    conn = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=Oracle;INIT=runscript from 'classpath:scripts/test.sql'");
    dao = new Dao(conn);
    ...
}
```